# Braintree ios sdk drop in controller doesn't proceed with payment

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, braintree

So I have integrated the Braintree iOS SDK and am using the drop in VC to request payment from the user. I am currently using the Sandbox mode and am attempting to use a fake credit card number for testing purposes (as described in braintree testing docs here https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/ruby):

[image: payscreen]

But once I click pay, it attempts to load but then nothing happens. There doesn't seem to be any log information.

Comment: Do you have log on server?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work for Braintree.</sub>

It looks like this is a problem with your iOS Braintree integration, but there isn’t enough information here to determine what the problem is.

I recommend reaching out to [Braintree support](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/) for help debugging your integration.